# Criar auto complete em input?

Tags: php, jquery, input, autocompletar

Quero fazer um efeito de `autocomplete` em um `input`, como um prompt, exemplo, tenho os seguintes comandos em um `array` php:

```
ADD 
SUB
SHOW
MUL
```

Quero fazer com que ao ele começar digitar, por exemplo digitar "`A`", exibir uma espécie de `placeholder` completando o comando, assim: **A**DD, porém não adicionando o "DD" já no input, apenas como "placeholder", e se o usuário apertar a tecla `TAB` por exemplo aí sim ele adiciona o "`DD`" ao `input`.

A minha maior dificuldade está a fazer esse efeito de placeholder no `input` não tenho a minima ideia de como fazer. Creio que o resto eu consigo fazer soziho, mas o ponto de partida (efeito de autocomplete) não tenho ideia de como fazer, podem dar uma luz?

Comment: Da uma olhada nesses exemplos: http://jsfiddle.net/sgxkj/

Comment: O exemplo do Gabriel você pode fazer sem javascript, apenas usando a tag datalist do html5 http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp

Comment: Sim Sim, ia falar isso kk o que eu queria é no dentro do input mesmo exibir a primeira opção